# Vector through a point with same distance as from this point to a line

Tags: vectors

I have three points $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^3$ (representing a triangle with area $a$). We know the distance from $C$ to $AB = d$. Now I need to find a vector that goes through $C$ (**not parallel** to $AB$), so that the distance from every point on this vector to $AB$ equals $d$. In other words that a triangle with vertices $A, B$ and any point of this vector will give the area $a$. Any tips will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think it exists. The points that are equally distant from $AB$ with distance $d$ form a circular cylinder or radius $d$ and axis $AB$. $C$ lies on this cylinder. The only generating lines of the cylinder are those that are parallel to $AB$. So, such a vector must be parallel $AB$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'm so sorry for the stupid question. Is there a way to at least find a single point (outside of the plane in which ABC lies) from which the altitude has the same distance to AB and it hits the surface of ABC perpendicularly?

Comment: If understand correctly, yes. Just draw the section of the above-mentioned cylinder through $C$ and perpendicular to axis $AB$. You get the circle. Any point on this circle will have the required property.